# how to embed Power BI report into application for organization

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to follow the tutorial located here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-your-organization

I was able to finish all steps until the beginning of the 'Embed your content using the sample application' section.  It states that I need to find and enter the values for ClientID and ClientSecret.  However, there are no such variables in the Cloud.config file that is in the sample application (located here: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples).  I'm assuming that these have been replaced by variables ApplicationID and ApplicationSecret, respectively.  Is this correct?

It also states to fill in the groupId and reportId values.  I'm assuming that these have also been replaced by WorkSpaceId and ReportId, respectively.  Is this correct as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Client ID is the Application ID from cloud. And GroupID is the WorkspaceID in PowerBI Service.